# How can I generate a list of function dependencies in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, dependencies, code-analysis

In order to distribute a function I've written that depends on other functions I've written that have their own dependencies and so on without distributing every m-file I have ever written, I need to figure out what the full list of dependencies is for a given m-file. Is there a built-in/freely downloadable way to do this?

Specifically I am interested in solutions for MATLAB 7.4.0 (R2007a), but if there is a different way to do it in older versions, by all means please add them here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For newer releases of Matlab (eg 2007 or 2008) you could use the built in functions:

1. mlint
2. dependency report and
3. coverage report

Another option is to use Matlab's profiler. The command is profile, it can also be used to track dependencies.  To use profile, you could do

```
>> profile on   % turn profiling on
>> foo;         % entry point to your matlab function or script
>> profile off  % turn profiling off
>> profview     % view the report
```

If profiler is not available, then perhaps the following two functions are (for pre-MATLAB 2015a):

1. depfun
2. depdir

For example,

```
>> deps = depfun('foo');
```

gives a structure, deps, that contains all the dependencies of foo.m.

From answers [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049918/4612), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34621308/4612), newer versions of MATLAB (post 2015a) use `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts` instead.

See answers

EDIT:

Caveats thanks to @Mike Katz comments

> - Remember that the Profiler will only
>     show you files that were actually used
>     in those runs, so if you don't go
>     through every branch, you may have
>     additional dependencies. The
>     dependency report is a good tool, but
>     only resolves static dependencies on
>     the path and just for the files in a
>     single directory.
> - Depfun is more reliable but gives you
>     every possible thing it can think of,
>     and still misses LOAD's and EVAL's.

Comment: Remember that the Profiler will only show you files that were actually used in those runs, so if you don't go through every branch, you may have additional dependencies. The dependency repot is a good tool, but only resolves static dependencies on the path and just for the files in a single dir.

Comment: Depfun is more reliable but gives you every possible thing it can think of, and still misses LOAD's and EVAL's.

Comment: Try exportToZip (link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10702).

It was pick of the week on September 18, 2009 (link: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/09/18/easier-and-less-error-prone-creation-of-zip-files/)

Comment: Update: in MATLAB 2015b, depfun and depdir have been removed (see answer below)

Answer (score 7):

For `MATLAB 2015a` and later you should preferably look at  [matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html)

or `doc matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`

because `depfun` is marked to be removed in a future release.