# hierarchy of functions in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have been reading someone else's `matlab` code and I don't know how the code structured. I mean I would like to know the hierarchy of functions, which function uses which function. I am reading the code to figure that out but its taking a lot of time.

So is there any other way I can see this hierarchy without reading the whole thing? To be honest it is starting to get confusing. Maybe `MatLab` has a built in function for that! I found this:

[How can I generate a list of function dependencies in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95760/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-function-dependencies-in-matlab)

but this doesn't seem to be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The [MATLAB profiler](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) will show you what functions are called by your code (and much more information to boot) and allow you to click through the hierarchy of function calls. You can either call `profile on` and then run your code, then call `profile off` and `profile viewer`, or you can simply call `profile viewer` and type a single line of code to run in the edit box at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dependency report provided in MATLAB:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html

There are also some tools on the File Exchange, such as [fdep](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17291-fdep-a-pedestrian-function-dependencies-finder).

Answer (score 0):

No idea about a function to show visible or depended-upon functions. However the basic rules are:

1) Only the first function in a .m file (normally has to have the same name as the file itself) is visible outside that file.

2) Any function can see any top level (see 1.) function if the file is in the matlab path. Matlab can show you the path so you know where it's hunting.

3) The order of the path is important, the first instance of a function called foo found in the path will be called. Obviously the current directory is at the top of the path.

3) All functions in a given file can see all other functions in that file.

That's the basics. No doubt there are other rules, and possibly exceptions to this. But that understanding generally serves me well.

Obviously the easiest way to work out which function is being called is to click on it in the editor and open it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I do is simply place in each function at the beginning `fprintf("inside function <name>/n");` and at the end of the function `fprintf("leaving function <name>/n");` where `<name>` is the name of the function.

This will give you a very specific list of which function is being called by which function (based on the order that they appear). Another thing like this would be to place `fprintf("function <name1> calling function <name2>/n");` so you can be more explicit about which function is being called by which one.