# Check dependencies in a MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, dependencies

Assume I have written two MATLAB functions `foo.m` and `bar.m`

I want to know if `foo.m` calls `bar.m`

I tried using `depfun` and listing dependencies and checking if `bar` is a member. It didn't work.

It seems `depfun` only returns `builtin` functions.

Is there a way around this when `bar.m` is not a built in function?

Comment: have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95760/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-function-dependencies-in-matlab) out?

Comment: I think it talks about depfun mostly

Comment: `depfun` does not only return builtin functions, but there could be situations in which it misses a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There are various techniques listed in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html) to identify file dependencies, one of them should do the trick.

***Note***: the techniques listed in the documentation page I mentioned are for the latest release R2014b, they may not all be available in earlier releases.